# Are ember-addons required to include ember-data and ember-qunit?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

So basically I made an ember-addon that doesn’t require ember-data nor ember-qunit (I wrote my tests using ember-cli-mocha), so I removed them and their dependencies from my `package.json` and `bower.json`.

The problem is when I try to build the addon, ember-cli complains about missing files with a message like this:

```
Path or pattern "bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js" did not match any files
```

If I add ember-data the message is the same only the path is a QUnit file:

```
Path or pattern "passed.png" did not match any files
```

Is there a way to completely remove `ember-data` and `ember-qunit` and be able to build?

Comment: `npm cache clean && bower cache clean && npm install && bower install`?

Comment: @SamSelikoff Didn’t work... :\

Comment: @givanse I ended up letting the packages in my addon, but updates have been made on ember-cli since then and I don’t know if it’s fixed or not. I haven’t re-tested it.